# NOT NULL constraint failed: news_comment.post_id

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

I bounced Into this error.
My Models.py file is

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='posts')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.message_html = misaka.html(self.message)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('news:single',kwargs={'username':self.user.username,'pk':self.pk})

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['-created_at']

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('news.Post',related_name='comments')
    aurthor = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    comment_html = models.TextField(editable = False)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.comment_html = misaka.html(self.comment)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('news:single',kwargs={'username':self.user.username,'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

and My Views.py file is

```
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.CreateView):
    model = models.Comment
    fields = ('comment',)

    login_url = "/users/login"

    def form_valid(self,form,*args,**kwargs):
        self.object = form.save(commit = False)
        self.object.aurthor = self.request.user
        #self.object.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        #print(self.request,self.kwargs['pk'])
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

And The error I get is

```
IntegrityError at /posts/4/comment/
NOT NULL constraint failed: news_comment.post_id
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/posts/4/comment/
Django Version: 1.11.3
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
NOT NULL constraint failed: news_comment.post_id
Exception Location: C:\Users\Sahil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 328
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Sahil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Sahil\\Documents\\GitHub\\news-for-good\\my_app',
 'C:\\Users\\Sahil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Sahil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Sahil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Sahil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Sahil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 25 Jul 2017 16:21:26 +0000
```

Can Anyone Please Tell What the error is.

If You need rest of the code [This My Github Repo](https://github.com/thecodinghub/news-for-good)

Thanks in Advance...
Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

You have forget to add **Post** `foreignkey` field save in views. because you did not defined `null=True` in post `foreignkey` field in **Comment** model. So you need to assign **Post** model instance when you are saving Comment model instance

```
def form_valid(self,form,*args,**kwargs):
        self.object = form.save(commit = False)
        self.object.aurthor = self.request.user
        self.object.post = # Assign Post model instance
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: how can we assing the post model